# AWS VPC Endpoints - Not functioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I am struggling to get my AWS VPC endpoints to work. I've missed something in the setup but cannot work it out.

I have a lambda that is triggered by an SQS entry, the lambda is within a VPC. The lambda is triggered and attempts to write to a different SQS queue.

When the lambda runs it times out attempting to write an SQS queue entry.

I have created a VPC endpoint for 'com.amazonaws.eu-west-2.sqs' (London Region) attached to that VPC. Reading the document it says I have to route traffic through the endpoint, but I have no idea how to do that.

Can anyone help me with what the next steps in setting this up are, or point me in the direction of documentation that provides the step by step approach (for someone who have very little networking knowledge).

Comment: Can I ask... Is there a particular reason why the AWS Lambda function is connected to the VPC? Is it also attempting to access resources that are inside the VPC? If not, the easiest thing to do is to **disconnect the Lambda function from the VPC** and it will automatically gain access to the Internet and the Amazon SQS endpoint.

Comment: If enclosing the Lambda inside the VPC is required by your use case, can you share to us how did you provision the VPC? Did you use CDK, ClickOps, CFN, terraform?

Comment: @AllanChua it was via ClickOps, I'm trying to get it to work before I put it in terraform.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein as you can see I am not used to working with VPCs. It is in a VPC to allow it to access an AWS RDS database more easily. To be honest accessing the database is the cause of the issues.

Comment: Follow this tutorial for SQS VPC private endpoint https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-sending-messages-from-vpc.html @BENBUNCoder

Answer (score 1):

To reproduce your situation I did the following (in the London region):

- Created an **Amazon SQS standard queue**
- Created an **IAM Role** for Lambda that has permission to write to the queue
- Used the VPC Wizard to **create a VPC**:

[image: VPC Wizard]

- Created a **Security Group for the Lambda function** (`Lambda-SG`) that **permits all Outbound traffic**
- Created an **AWS Lambda function** and configured it to use a **private subnet** in the VPC, and associated the `Lambda-SG` security group with the function:

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    sqs = boto3.client('sqs')

    queue_url = 'https://sqs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/782031212076/stack'

    # Send message to SQS queue
    response = sqs.send_message(QueueUrl=queue_url, MessageBody='Foo')

    
    print(f"Message ID: {response['MessageId']}")
```

I then **invoked the Lambda function** by pressing the **Test** button (and using the default test values) and received the error:

> "errorMessage": "2023-12-03T11:15:03.853Z 048c31a5-6760-44d6-a9f3-3bd84a787e88 Task timed out after 3.01 seconds"

**This is expected** since the Lambda function is connected to a private subnet that does not have a VPC Endpoint for SQS.

- Created a **Security Group for the endpoint** (`Endpoint-SG`) that permits All inbound traffic from `Lambda-SG` (That is, the Inbound rule in `Endpoint-SG` specifically references `Lambda-SG`)
- Added a **VPC Endpoint for SQS** to the **private subnet** of the VPC
- Confirmed connectivity using the VPC Reachability Analyzer:

[image: VPC Reachability Analyzer]

- Used **Test** to run the Lambda function again

It worked:

```
Function Logs
START RequestId: 5a0d6359-1f57-4e50-98a1-4de6ccacd9b9 Version: $LATEST
Message ID: f1b46e9a-981d-4e92-9864-501b4ccb8db0
END RequestId: 5a0d6359-1f57-4e50-98a1-4de6ccacd9b9
REPORT RequestId: 5a0d6359-1f57-4e50-98a1-4de6ccacd9b9  Duration: 1332.49 ms    Billed Duration: 1333 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 74 MB  Init Duration: 249.31 ms
```

I will admit that, after adding the VPC Endpoint, the function still had a timeout. That's why I used the VPC Reachability Analyzer to test the connection. It said everything should work okay. Then, when I tried the Lambda function again, it worked successfully. So, **there might be a delay between adding the VPC Endpoint and having it work correctly**.

Hopefully you can compare your setup with the above steps to see what differs. I recommend that you start by examining the Security Group on the Lambda function and the Security Group on the VPC Endpoint. These should be **different Security Groups** -- one with an Outbound rule and one with an Inbound rule.

Comment: I am trying to solve a similar kind of issue. I have a question regarding the traceability analysis. What did you use as the source? I see a network interface, but how did you select that?

Comment: @Malintha When an AWS Lambda function is connected to a VPC, it will create a Network Interface. If you go to the EC2 management console and look at Network Interfaces, it should be listed with a "Interface Type" of 'lambda'. The description should include the name of the Lambda function, but I think it is possible that multiple Lambda functions might share a Network Interface in the same subnet. Once you know which Network Interface is being used by Lambda, you can get the Network Interface ID and use that in the Reachability Analyzer.

Comment: Yes @John Rotenstein. I found it in the ENI list and I did the reachability analysis with that.